# How to add hover tooltips and add to cart option for mulitple products in a image

Tags: hover, tooltip, e-commerce, graphic

What is the best way to create an image of a motorcycle for example and show a tooltip and add to cart option for each part that is hovered over?

Answer (score 0):

A HTML5 Canvas might suit your needs but this will require quite a lot of calculation in Javascript.

Checking coordinates:
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-mouse-coordinates/

How to draw images:
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-images/

After that you can do a hover check using the X-Y coordinates of your mouse to determine which popup to show.